# How to convert list of tuples to dict without losing order

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to count the letter frequency in a string using Dict, sorted in alphabetical order. The output should be a dictionary only.

Here's my attempt.

```
    s = raw_input()
    arr = {}
    for i in s :
        if i in arr :
            arr[i] += 1
        else :
            arr[i] = 1
    x = sorted(arr.items())
    print dict(x)
```

Input :

```
amphisofttechnologies
```

Expected Output :

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'e': 2, 'f': 1, 'g': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 2, 'l': 1, 'm': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 3, 'p': 1, 's': 2, 't': 2}
```

My Output :

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 'e': 2, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 2, 'h': 2, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 3, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 2, 't': 2}
```

Kindly point out where I am making the mistake.

Comment: You could use `OrderedDict(sorted(Counter(s).items()))`.

Answer (score 1):

Python dict explicitly doesn't guarantee/keep order between keys. So what you are asking can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).